# Django + Uvicorn

Tags: python, django, uvicorn

I'm trying to use Django 3.0 with Uvicorn and getting this on start:

```
INFO:     Started server process [96219]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     ASGI 'lifespan' protocol appears unsupported.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
```

I could turn lifespan off with the `--lifespan off` flag, but is there a way to have it work with Django? A quick search for Django + lifespan seems to not return anything.

Answer (score 9):

No, `lifespan` protocol doesn't work with Django 3.0.

See this ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31508

Answer (score 2):

**Here's the initial setup I used with django 3.1 / 3.2**

EDIT: some rough performance benchmarks: https://github.com/allen-munsch/benchmark-django-fastapi

#### old version

`your_django/old_wsgi.py`:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "your_django.settings")

application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

Previously run as:

```
newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn your_django.old_wsgi \
-k eventlet --log-file - --timeout 60
```

#### new version

`your_django/asgi.py`:

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import ASGIStaticFilesHandler

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "pm.settings")

application = ASGIStaticFilesHandler(
    get_asgi_application()
)
```

And to run

```
gunicorn your_django.asgi --log-level=debug -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker \
--log-file - --timeout 60

# OR for local dev

uvicorn --reload your_django.asgi
```

related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/67275668/2026508

Comment: any idea how to throw Channels in the mix here?

Answer (score 2):

As @KubaMisiorny [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61590397/3627387). Django does not support [Lifespan Protocol](https://asgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specs/lifespan.html).

If you would like to disable this protocol, you have a couple of options depending on what your setup is.

### Running `uvicorn`

Pass `--lifespan off` option.

`uvicorn --lifespan off`

### Running `gunicorn` with `uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker`

You will need to pass config arguments by creating a subclass of the worker class

Create `uvicorn_worker.py`

```py
from uvicorn.workers import UvicornWorker as BaseUvicornWorker


# Django does not support Lifespan Protocol
# https://asgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specs/lifespan.html
# https://github.com/django/django/pull/13636
# https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31508
# Using uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker throws INFO warning:
#   "ASGI 'lifespan' protocol appears unsupported."
# To avoid that we need to disable 'lifespan' in the worker
class UvicornWorker(BaseUvicornWorker):
    CONFIG_KWARGS = {"lifespan": "off"}
```

In `gunicorn.conf.py`

```
# https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/#gunicorn
# using custom one to disable Lifespan Protocol
# needs to be passed by string https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1539
worker_class = "uvicorn_worker.UvicornWorker"
```