# Architecture Flask vs FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

I have been tinkering around Flask and FastAPI to see how it acts as a server.
One of the main things that I would like to know is how Flask and FastAPI deal with multiple requests from multiple clients.
Especially when the code has efficiency issues (long database query time).

So, I tried making a simple code to understand this problem.
The code is simple, when the client access the route, the application sleeps for 10 seconds before it returns results.
It looks something like this:

**FastAPI**

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from time import sleep
app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
async def root():
    print('Sleeping for 10')
    sleep(10)
    print('Awake')
    return {'message': 'hello'}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

**Flask**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from time import sleep

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Root(Resource):
    def get(self):
        print('Sleeping for 10')
        sleep(10)
        print('Awake')
        return {'message': 'hello'}

api.add_resource(Root, '/')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Once the applications are up, I tried accessing them at the same time through 2 different chrome clients.
The below are the results:

**FastAPI**

[image]

**Flask**

[image]

As you can see, for FastAPI, the code first waits 10 seconds before processing the next request. Whereas for Flask, the code processes the next request while the 10-second sleep is still happening.

Despite doing a bit of googling, there is not really a straight answer on this topic.
If anyone has any comments that can shed some light on this, please drop them in the comments.

Your opinions are all appreciated. Thank you all very much for your time.

**EDIT**
An update on this, I am exploring a bit more and found this concept of Process manager. For example, we can run uvicorn using a process manager (gunicorn). By adding more workers, I am able to achieve something like Flask. Still testing the limits of this, however.
https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/

Thanks to everyone who left comments! Appreciate it.

Comment: The most important part regarding performance and concurrency if not the framework used but the WSGI server and it's settings. (The built-in dev server is not suitable for production.) In an extensive tests I did I notice that it can make the diffetence between "fails under load" and "hundreds of requests per second".

Comment: Future readers might find [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) helpful

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This seemed a little interesting, so i ran a little tests with `ApacheBench`:

**Flask**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class Root(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {"message": "hello"}


api.add_resource(Root, "/")
```

**FastAPI**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI


app = FastAPI(debug=False)


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "hello"}
```

I ran 2 tests for FastAPI, there was a huge difference:

1. `gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker fast_api:app`
2. `uvicorn fast_api:app --reload`

So here is the benchmarking results for 5000 requests with a concurrency of 500:

**FastAPI with Uvicorn Workers**

```
Concurrency Level:      500
Time taken for tests:   0.577 seconds
Complete requests:      5000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      720000 bytes
HTML transferred:       95000 bytes
Requests per second:    8665.48 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       57.700 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.115 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          1218.58 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    6   4.5      6      30
Processing:     6   49  21.7     45     126
Waiting:        1   42  19.0     39     124
Total:         12   56  21.8     53     127

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     53
  66%     64
  75%     69
  80%     73
  90%     81
  95%     98
  98%    112
  99%    116
 100%    127 (longest request)
```

**FastAPI - Pure Uvicorn**

```
Concurrency Level:      500
Time taken for tests:   1.562 seconds
Complete requests:      5000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      720000 bytes
HTML transferred:       95000 bytes
Requests per second:    3200.62 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       156.220 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.312 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          450.09 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    8   4.8      7      24
Processing:    26  144  13.1    143     195
Waiting:        2  132  13.1    130     181
Total:         26  152  12.6    150     203

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    150
  66%    155
  75%    158
  80%    160
  90%    166
  95%    171
  98%    195
  99%    199
 100%    203 (longest request)
```

**For Flask**:

```
Concurrency Level:      500
Time taken for tests:   27.827 seconds
Complete requests:      5000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      830000 bytes
HTML transferred:       105000 bytes
Requests per second:    179.68 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       2782.653 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       5.565 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          29.13 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0   87 293.2      0    3047
Processing:    14 1140 4131.5    136   26794
Waiting:        1 1140 4131.5    135   26794
Total:         14 1227 4359.9    136   27819

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    136
  66%    148
  75%    179
  80%    198
  90%    295
  95%   7839
  98%  14518
  99%  27765
 100%  27819 (longest request)
```

### Total results

**Flask**:     *Time taken for tests:   27.827 seconds*

**FastAPI - Uvicorn**:     *Time taken for tests:   1.562 seconds*

**FastAPI - Uvicorn Workers**: *Time taken for tests:   0.577 seconds*

---

With Uvicorn Workers FastAPI is nearly **48x** faster than Flask, which is very understandable. **ASGI vs WSGI**, so i ran with 1 concurreny:

**FastAPI - UvicornWorkers**: *Time taken for tests:   1.615 seconds*

**FastAPI - Pure Uvicorn**: *Time taken for tests:   2.681 seconds*

**Flask**: *Time taken for tests:   5.541 seconds*

### I ran more tests to test out Flask with a production server.

### 5000 Request 1000 Concurrency

**Flask with Waitress**

```
Server Software:        waitress
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            8000

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        21 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1000
Time taken for tests:   3.403 seconds
Complete requests:      5000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      830000 bytes
HTML transferred:       105000 bytes
Requests per second:    1469.47 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       680.516 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.681 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          238.22 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    4   8.6      0      30
Processing:    31  607 156.3    659     754
Waiting:        1  607 156.3    658     753
Total:         31  611 148.4    660     754

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    660
  66%    678
  75%    685
  80%    691
  90%    702
  95%    728
  98%    743
  99%    750
 100%    754 (longest request)
```

**Gunicorn with Uvicorn Workers**

```
Server Software:        uvicorn
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            8000

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        19 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1000
Time taken for tests:   0.634 seconds
Complete requests:      5000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      720000 bytes
HTML transferred:       95000 bytes
Requests per second:    7891.28 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       126.722 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.127 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          1109.71 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0   28  13.8     30      62
Processing:    18   89  35.6     86     203
Waiting:        1   75  33.3     70     171
Total:         20  118  34.4    116     243

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    116
  66%    126
  75%    133
  80%    137
  90%    161
  95%    189
  98%    217
  99%    230
 100%    243 (longest request)
```

Pure Uvicorn, but this time 4 workers `uvicorn fastapi:app --workers 4`

```
Server Software:        uvicorn
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            8000

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        19 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1000
Time taken for tests:   1.147 seconds
Complete requests:      5000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      720000 bytes
HTML transferred:       95000 bytes
Requests per second:    4359.68 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       229.375 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.229 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          613.08 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0   20  16.3     17      70
Processing:    17  190  96.8    171     501
Waiting:        3  173  93.0    151     448
Total:         51  210  96.4    184     533

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    184
  66%    209
  75%    241
  80%    260
  90%    324
  95%    476
  98%    504
  99%    514
 100%    533 (longest request)
```

Comment: How did you run flask app? It is strange it takes 2.7 seconds in each request for such a simple example...

Comment: @marianobianchi i ran with `app.run()` , with a high concurrency it's not that strange i think.

Comment: That's what I thought. You are comparing a production-ready server like uvicorn with a development server like Werkzeug. You should compare with flask running with waitress, which is the recommended way of deploying a production ready flask app: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/deploy/#run-with-a-production-server

Comment: @marianobianchi great, actually i benchmarked from OP's code, but i will ran the tests again with waitress and update the question with new results , thanks!

Comment: accurate analysis, we are compromised almost migrate to FastAPI for new versions of our products. I came across even more  delays in debug mode specifically when was using behind reverse proxy.

Comment: And yes. There is a WSGIMIDDLEWARE for fastapi. It enables fastapi wsgi option. Could you pls try that with gunicorn with meinheld workers?

Comment: @YagizDegirmenci: why not compare apples with apples and run Flask with `gunicorn` too (and the same number of workers). This would be even more fair comparison IMO than using `waitress` (see: https://stackshare.io/stackups/gunicorn-vs-waitress).

Comment: @YagizDegirmenci, what is the command you have used to run "Gunicorn with Uvicorn Workers" test. i mean `gunicorn -k uvicorn.workers.xxx -w x` and what machine(num cpu threads, ram and OS) did you run this on? or were these tests run on docker on raw metal?

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala I ran the tests with 4 workers without docker, i don't remember the specs of the machine but should be 8 CPU.

Comment: Do [flask 2.0's `async` capabilities](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/async-await/) change that picture?

Comment: why arent you running Flask with workers as well? This makes no sense...

Answer (score 31):

You are using the `time.sleep()` function, in a `async` endpoint. `time.sleep()` is blocking and should never be used in asynchronous code. What you should be using is probably the `asyncio.sleep()` function:

```
import asyncio
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
async def root():
    print('Sleeping for 10')
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print('Awake')
    return {'message': 'hello'}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

That way, each request will take ~10 sec to complete, but you will be able to serve multiple requests concurrently.

In general, async frameworks offer replacements for all blocking functions inside the standard library (sleep functions, IO functions, etc.). You are meant to use those replacements when writing async code and (optionally) `await` them.

Some non-blocking frameworks and libraries such as gevent, do not offer replacements. They instead monkey-patch functions in the standard library to make them non-blocking. This is not the case, as far as I know, for the newer async frameworks and libraries though, because they are meant to allow the developer to use the async-await syntax.

Answer (score 12):

#### Why code is slow

Blocking operations will stop your event loop running the tasks. When you are calling the `sleep()` function, all the tasks (requests) are waiting until it's finished, thus killing all the benefits of asynchronous code execution.

To understand why this code is wrong for comparison, we should better understand how asynchronous code works in Python and have some knowledge of GIL. Concurrency and async code are well explained in the [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/) of FastAPI.

@Asotos has described why your code is slow and yes, you should use coroutines for I/O operations since they don't block the event loop from execution (`time.sleep()` is a blocking I/O operation, but coroutine `asyncio.sleep()` is a non-blocking I/O operation). It is reasonably suggested to use async functions so that the event loop is not blocked, but for now, not all libraries have async versions.

#### Optimization without `async` functions and `asyncio.sleep`

In case you cannot use the async version of the library, you can simply define your route functions as simple `def` functions, not `async def`.

If the route function is defined as synchronous (`def`), FastAPI will smartly call this function in an external thread pool, and the main thread with event loop will not be blocked, and your benchmarks will be much better without using `await asyncio.sleep()`. Greatly explained in [this](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#path-operation-functions) section.

#### Solution

```py
from time import sleep

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI


app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
def root():
    print('Sleeping for 10')
    sleep(10)
    print('Awake')
    return {'message': 'hello'}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

BTW, you won't gain a lot of benefits, if operations run in the thread pool are CPU bound (e.g. heavy calculations) because of [GIL](https://realpython.com/python-gil/). CPU-bound tasks must be run in separate processes.

Answer (score 10):

I think you are blocking an event queue in FastAPI which is asynchronous framework whereas in Flask requests are probably run each in new thread. Move all CPU bound tasks to separate processes or in your FastAPI example just sleep on event loop (do not use time.sleep here). In FastAPI run IO bound tasks asynchronously

Answer (score 1):

The difference in handling multiple requests between Flask and FastAPI stems from their architectural designs and the way they manage asynchronous operations. FastAPI, built on top of Starlette and Uvicorn, inherently supports asynchronous request handling, allowing it to process multiple requests concurrently without waiting for one to complete if the functions are defined with async and awaitable operations are properly used (e.g., await asyncio.sleep(10) instead of sleep(10)). This means that, in theory, FastAPI can start processing a new request even if a previous one is awaiting completion of a non-blocking operation.

Answer (score -1):

What actually need to do in FastAPI is actually using Background Tasks in real scenario which you may sending email or doing heavy query on database and something like that

FastAPI

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, BackgroundTasks
import time
app = FastAPI()

def sleep(msg):
    time.sleep(10)
    print(msg)

@app.get('/')
async def root(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    msg= 'Sleeping for 10'
    background_tasks.add_task(sleep, msg)
    print('Awake')
    return {'message': 'hello'}
```

then try check benchmarks